# Can't call the external CSS property from external css from Views in CodeIgniter

Tags: css, codeigniter

I'm having some trouble , when it comes to calling the external `CSS` property in Code Igniter. I have a custom css file called `custom.css` and it is from the assets folder. However, when I am calling it from a View, it does not call it. I have the property as follows:

```
.project-description{
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px;
}
```

I have a custom view called display.php and I call it as follows:

```
    <p id='project-description'>
        <?php echo $project_data->project_body; ?>
    </p>
```

And in my main view which is the layouts in which I call the external css file to which the css property resides:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/custom.css">
```

In the custom view which is the display.php, it does not call the CSS property even though I already include the external CSS file. What will be the solution to this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with this code:

Your `<p>` element specifies it's **ID** as `project-description`, 
However you've specified it as a **Class** in your CSS file.

The prefix for an **ID** is `#`,
The prefix for a **Class** is `.`

**Classes** can be used more than once in an HTML page,
**ID's** can be used ONLY ONCE.

If you would only like to use this type of element once on the page, you need to change your CSS file to use `#project-description` rather than `.project-description`

If you would like to use this type of element more than once on the page, you need to change your HTML file to use:

```
<p id='project-description'>
```

To:

```
<p class='project-description'>
```

The second "problem" is that the CSS URL is being grabbed in a weird way. (I would fix it for readability/consistency)

Currently you have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/custom.css">
```

I think it needs to be changed to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/custom.css'); ?>">
```

If this doesn't solve the problem, it might be because an old version of a CSS file is cached, and its not being reloaded with the newest most up-to-date version. This can be a problem when making many changes to your CSS. When making changes to a CSS file, you can put a version number on the end like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/custom.css?version=0.1'); ?>">
```

Every time you update the CSS file, you can change the version number and it will MAKE SURE to reload the CSS file, or else you may be getting a cached version of your CSS file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I forgot to edit my question regarding the class one when calling the css class, but thanks for your help. appreciate it..

Answer (score 1):

I have see your code of css. You have use:

```
.project-description{
background-color: #fff;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 6px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px;}
```

You have use . symbole in css and you have use in html is id:

```
<p id='project-description'>
    <?php echo $project_data->project_body; ?>
</p>
```

There is two way to correct your code.

1. ## project-description{ }

   use # in the css property.
2. Change in your HTML file id to class.

Answer (score 0):

After recently going from my files if there are any problems, I experimented it when I view the project on Firefox and it does work!. And I just restarted my browser in order for the CSS call to work..